# why indexof is returning -1 when element exists in the text

Tags: c#

```
   var str = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><AT.crm:ATUpdatePriorityRamm61 xmlns:AT.crm='http://AT.crm.com/ASB'><incident.Id>be07f1c7-6055-e611-80e7-3863bb2eb408</incident.Id></AT.crm:ATUpdatePriorityRamm61>";
            var index = str.IndexOf("</At.crm:ATUpdatePriorityRamm61>");
```

Value of index I am getting is -1? Why, you can clearly see the text is present in the str string.

Comment: There is something wrong, lower case and upper case. "AT" and "At". Thats why result -1.

Comment: As an aside, if you're dealing with XML I'd strongly suggest using something like LINQ to XML rather than handling it as a string.

Comment: It doesn't match, because you're not searching for the right thing.

Comment: Btw, an indexOf overload takes a string comparison argument you can use for case insensitivity.

Comment: @x... It worked. Can you put it in an answer so that I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities how to fix that error.

- Pass the correct string: i.e. correct character casing
- use string.IndexOf(string, StringComparison).

.

```
str.IndexOf("</At.crm:ATUpdatePriorityRamm61>", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```